# pass alt code combination as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

I have a simple method that accepts a string:

```
private void drawTextboxValue(string text)
{
    // lots of code
    g.DrawString(text, font, brush, layout);
}
```

I should pass alt code "Alt 0149" as the string so it will draw a bullet point (see: http://duena.telenet.be/ALT_toetsen_lijst.htm).

I know you could draw something else to achieve this (an ellipse for example), but for some reason I'm not allowed to do that - I'm only allowed to pass another parameter to this method.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write Unicode characters in C# here is an example

```
string a = "\u0149";
```

> The escape code \udddd (where dddd is a four-digit number) represents
>   the Unicode character U+dddd. Eight-digit Unicode escape codes are
>   also recognized: \Udddddddd

[string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

Comment: here is a list of unicode symbols: http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2600-26FF ENJOY :)

Comment: @dotctor: Make that __"\u2022"__ !!

Comment: Hm. My machine is set up German. I didn't know that in Unicode there still are differences..?  Here µ is U00B5 (Alt+0181) and the Bullet • is U2022 (Alt+0149).